# Postgres sqlx prepared statement with table name bindvar

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, prepared-statement

I am trying to create a prepared statement in using the Golang sqlx library. I want to have the table name be a bindVar

```
stmt, err := stmtTx.Preparex("SELECT * FROM $1 WHERE question_id=$2;")
```

However this gives me an syntax error around `/$1/`. Can I not use a bind var for the table name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I not use a bind var for the table name?

No, [source of quote.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/xfunc-sql.html)

> The arguments can only be used as data values, not as identifiers.
>   Thus for example this is reasonable:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ($1);
> ```
>
> but this will not work:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO $1 VALUES (42);
> ```

But you can use `fmt.Sprintf` for the table name if you want but leave the $1, $2, ... for the data values.

Comment: But does `fmt.Sprintf` understand identifier quoting rules? There should be a function in the database interface specifically for properly quoting identifiers.

Comment: @muistooshort No, just for the table name.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. Identifiers (such as table and column names) have quoting and escaping rules that are different than those for, say, strings. There should be functions in the database interface that know how to properly quote identifiers.

Comment: I usually have simple table names,  so I'm not sure about escaping rules.

Answer (score 0):

See this page for a general solution:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ecpg-dynamic.html